# Does google consider bounce rate, if the user right click open in a new tab and continue on google clicking some more link?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, bounce-rate

Does google consider bounce rate, if the user  right click open in a new tab and continue on google clicking some more link ?

Is this correct?

In my opinion the work for bounce rate is to determine, whether a user have found relevant for what he is searching in a simple organised way.

Answer (score 2):

If Google is keeping track of a user's visit, then they *probably* will consider coming back to their search results in a new tab as bouncing back to find another relative link in the search results. This is because there is real no concept of new windows or tabs to website. Just visits. Additionally, there is no way for them to know you kept the previous website open in a new tab or window.

So by coming back to the search results in a new tab or window it should look like a "bounce" to Google.

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse "bounce rate" with "time on site" or "return to Google time". These are three different metrics that have different meanings.

Bounce rate is the percentage of visitors who only loaded one page on a site they visit without any regard to the length of the time of visit. Many sites have a high bounce rate due to their nature (news aggregation, app hosting, even Q&A like here) but this doesn't reflect on their quality. Some sites, like ecommerce sites, will want to have lower bounce rates because they need to engage visitors across their whole site.

Time on Site is how long the visitor maintains an open session with the site. They could hit as many or as few pages as they want. What matters is how long they're on the site. Once again, different types of sites will show different statistical patterns.

Return to Google time is the measurement Google uses to determine how long it took for a user to return to Google after a click-thru. They aggregate this data and draw statistical analysis from it. Behaviors like opening another window/tab are probably dropped as statistical outliers.